# Why div is taking extra space for images?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the text just on the side of images but I don't know why my image div is taking extra spaces

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.round img {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.round{
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: left;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="round">
        <img mat-card-image  src="https://scontent-bom1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/46463461_1157513267757941_7425556584253620224_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ht=scontent-bom1-1.xx&oh=3f957c2a41da24c5f0c505d61241fba5&oe=5C7550A3" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a routerLink="#">Rupesh Yadav</a></p>
      <p><i>April,12,2018</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: the width should be defined on round instead of the image

Comment: how about limiting the height and width of image using `max-height` and `max-width`

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I tried width but got same result

Comment: Add `flex: 0` and set dimension on image

Comment: @BonishKoirala, same result

Answer (score 3):

You need to define css in `.round` class not in img, and add `width:100%` in img css.

It's by default distribution within a flexbox to adjust the space.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.round {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;  
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: left; 
}

.round img {
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="round">
      <img mat-card-image  src="https://scontent-bom1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/46463461_1157513267757941_7425556584253620224_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ht=scontent-bom1-1.xx&oh=3f957c2a41da24c5f0c505d61241fba5&oe=5C7550A3" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a routerLink="#">Rupesh Yadav</a></p>
      <p><i>April,12,2018</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can just add width in pixel in image it also work:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.round img {
  width: 150px;  
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="round">
      <img mat-card-image  src="https://scontent-bom1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/46463461_1157513267757941_7425556584253620224_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ht=scontent-bom1-1.xx&oh=3f957c2a41da24c5f0c505d61241fba5&oe=5C7550A3" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a routerLink="#">Rupesh Yadav</a></p>
      <p><i>April,12,2018</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't explain why the problem happens in  the first place. Why would the first div take up so much space that the second div is squeezed to the side? There's nothing in the source causing that. That is what the real question should be.

Comment: Is it to do with the default distribution within a flexbox?

Comment: @MrLister Sorry for that, I was in just hurry to get the working result. I should have asked the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

You used display flex property as row but not sized flex column try below example hope that help you.

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.round {
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-pack: left;
    -ms-flex-pack: left;
    justify-content: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.round img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;

}
```